# MacBook Pro 13" 2020 Bluetooth Connectivity Issue

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth

My MacBook Pro 2020 (with 2 usb C ports) seems to have a Bluetooth connectivity issue, and I'm curious whether this is something widely acknowledged or it's just me who's having this problem.

I'm using a magic mouse 1st gen, and I don't have any problem using it alone. I also don't have any problem even when I use it with some old Bluetooth headphones (Klipsch R6). But when I have the machine paired with either SONY WF-100XM3 or 1More ANC Neckband earbuds, in addition to the mouse, I get connectivity issues within a minute. The connection is so unstable to the point where I just can't use the headphones anymore.

Interestingly, when I unpair the magic mouse, then everything is fine. So it's not the headphones or the mouse themselves but a combination of them that seems to cause trouble. It looks as though my macbook cannot handle the amount of data flowing through its Bluetooth module if more than one device is connected at the same time, especially one of them demands a lot of data.

Is there anyone who's having a similar issue? What would be a solution to this?

Comment: I have to say that I experienced similar problems when using an MxMaster mouse and Bluetooth headphones, yet on an older 2017 15" MBP. My solution was to get a dongle for the mouse

Comment: @X_841 Thanks, which dongle do you use? I was thinking about the same solution, but it looks like almost all BT dongles on the market are for Windows.

Comment: It is a Unifying BT dongle from Logitech for Logitech mice. There is no dongle or similar for the Magic Mouse from Apple. Have you tried calling Apple support about this issue?

Comment: Oh, I see. I think I can't give up my magic mouse. I haven't tried Apple support, but perhaps I should. I'll let you know if I get anything useful from them.